# Two actions, one requires selection and the other does not. Should I keep separate behaviors or make it uniform?

Tags: usability

[image]

There are two actions in the listing: one sends a message, and the other exports a CSV.

A selection is required to send a message, but not for exporting a CSV. We could make selection required for export as well.

What should I do:

- "Send Message" and "Export" are both enabled only if people are selected?
- "Send Message" enabled if people are selected, and "Export" works independently?

Comment: Could you make the export button only export selections (if there are any), otherwise export all?

Comment: That is fine but what you suggest? both is possible for me. should I make it uniform?

Comment: I'll formalize my thoughts in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, I think you could have two behaviors for the export button:

- Users Selected: The export button downloads CSV data of those users
- Users not Selected: The export button downloads CSV data of all listed users

If you don't wish to implement that, consider renaming the button to "Export Results" or "Export All" to indicate the selection doesn't affect it.